# Bad Compile Constant Value || Instant-Specific Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, networking, compiler-errors, sql-loader

I am trying to connect with remote sql server database. When I write this connection string then I got "Bad Compile Constant value".

**"Data Source=Machine-Name\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=HODB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user_id;Password=password"**

but if I write this without Machine-Name then I got this error at con.open();.

**"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"**

Please give me solution.

Comment: You need to escape the "\" in the connection string, i.e. `Data Source=Machine-Name\\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=HODB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user_id;Password=password`. Currently your compiler is picking up `\S` as an escape sequence and it is not a valid one.

Comment: Thank you Dear. Solved. Infect sometime mind become stuck in minor thing.